# MVC: NLog - файл конфигурации

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, логирование, nlog

**Добрый день!**

в статье [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176001/) сказано - установите пакет NLog, потом добавьте запись в веб-конфиг проекта, а потом куда-то встунуть этот код:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C://file.txt" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Гугл говорит, что должен быть еще 1 конфиг-файл: NLog.config, куда его и надо поместить. Я добавил пустой конфиг файл и так и сделал, но логи не заработали.

Подскажите, я правильно сделал? Или надо было как-то по-другому?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> После установки пользуемся документацией на NLog (https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial) и добавляем в Web.config

Ответ на вопрос - *web.config*.

Получится как-то так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
    <!-- ... описание других секций ... -->
  </configSections>
  <!-- ... другие секции ... -->
  <nlog autoReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C://file.txt" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Или можно настроить разные варианты вывода логов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
    <!-- ... описание других секций ... -->
  </configSections>
  <!-- ... другие секции ... -->
  <nlog autoReload="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/Content/logs/${shortdate}" />
    <targets>
      <target name="TcpOutlet" xsi:type="NLogViewer" address="tcp4://localhost:4505"/>
      <target name="fileLogTrace" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/trace.txt" />
      <target name="fileLogDebug" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/debug.txt" />
      <target name="fileLogInfo" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/info.txt" />
      <target name="fileLogErrors" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/errors.txt" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="TcpOutlet" />
      <logger name="*" level="Trace" writeTo="fileLogTrace" />
      <logger name="*" level="Debug" writeTo="fileLogDebug" />
      <logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="fileLogInfo" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="fileLogErrors" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```